# Best practice for animating a few 2d sprites on screen

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, sprite

I want to add a few animated sprites to my application, drawn from spritesheets. There would never be more than three on screen at any time.

As I was researching this topic, I came across several technologies that support drawing and animating the sprites including lib gles, libgdx, cocos 2d etc...

However, because I believe I have a fairly simple use case, I was wondering if it is typically necessary to bring in these libraries to my project just to animate a few sprites? What is typically the recommended way to go about solving my problem that would not have a huge hit on performance?

Comment: I have experience only with libgdx but I can tell it's awesome. Easy to use, versatile if you get familiar with it, it take only a couple minutes to make an animated sprite appear. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation Here you can see what does it take to write a working example.

Comment: I'm under the impression that I can't just import libgdx as a library into my existing android project, but that I need to start with a blank libgdx project. How would I then go about incorporating my existing android project into a libgdx one? and will regular android activities still work in a libgdx project?